# Customizing the figure caption

Tags: formatting, captions

In my part of document (and also beamer slides), I would like to write something like this in the figure caption,

Figure. X: A lazy **old** fox.

instead of,

Figure. X: A lazy old fox.

I couldn't typeset it when I use this,

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{figure}
\caption{A lazy \textbf{old} fox}
\end{figure}
```

Can someone point out my mistake and also provide a solution for this. Moreover, I am using pdflatex for preparing the documents.

Comment: We'll need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to help you further, since this one is working perfectly (i.e. old is bold) for me: `\documentclass{scrartcl}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \caption{A lazy \textbf{old} fox}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}`

Comment: @ebo I am using several .sty files and many packages, can you suggest me how to create a minimal working example out of that.

Comment: I could not do better than [this](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/64454)! `(-;` Creating a MWE is tedious, but most of the time, it's the easiest way to solve your issue (even easier than to post on TeX.SE!)

Comment: @ebo I shall try to create one as soon as possible :p